# can't combine [autofocus="autofocus"] with :input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to build a query that finds elements that have the autofocus-attribute and are also inputs(or selects).

using this Skeleton....

```
<html><head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maindiv">
        <form class="someclass">
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="text" autofocus="autofocus" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

... i try

```
$('#maindiv .someclass [autofocus="autofocus"]')
```

Which returns one input, as expected

```
$('#maindiv .someclass :input')
```

Returns both inputs.

But combining the two always results in an empty list.

```
$('#maindiv .someclass [autofocus="autofocus"]:input')
$('#maindiv .someclass :input[autofocus="autofocus"]')
$('#maindiv .someclass :input').filter('[autofocus="autofocus"]')
```

This one

```
$('#maindiv .someclass [autofocus="autofocus"]').filter(':input')
```

works and returns one input.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a bug happening until version 1.6 of jQuery and is fixed in 1.7 where the code works.

Comment: Ha - yeah - my fiddle breaks with jq 1.6.4 - go figure.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#maindiv .someclass :input[autofocus="autofocus"]');
```

is correct.  See [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M7xVe/3/).  It's getting an input with the autofocs attribute set, anywhere within an element with class someclass, inside of maindiv.

Check your actual code for errors.

Comment: It works in the demo you posted(thx for the link btw, cool site). The same code does however not work on my machine. So that's weird. This is probably a sublte bug in either my browser/os/jquery-version at work. thx

Comment: @KarlsFriend - not sure.  I'm tempted recommend you check that this code is in your document.ready handler, not your other code is working, so that wouldn't explain it, so I guess I'm not sure.